# adding the value of a column into a LIKE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-like

i have 3 tables for tags, tag categories and used tags. i'm wanting to get a list of all tags with a count of the used tags (the format of the tags used is comma separated values for each document id that has tags).

i've been trying something like this but I can't get the value of the tags.tag field to be inserted into the LIKE statement.

`SELECT categories.category, tags.tag,

(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM usedtags WHERE usedtags.value LIKE '%tags.tag%') as numtags

FROM tags

LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = tags.category_id

ORDER BY categories.category, tags.tag`

There must be a better way to do this but my SQL is not good enough!!

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, perhaps:

> WHERE [column] LIKE [OtherColumn] + '%'

I also want to point out a major performance problem in your current plan.  You're trying to use an initial wild card in your search, like this: `LIKE '%tags.tag%'`.  That is very bad, because it doesn't work with your indexes.  We would say that it's not **sargable**.  Any time you find yourself wanting to use an initial wild card like that, you should look at a [full-text index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879306.aspx) instead.  It's not that hard and will dramatically improve your database performance.

Comment: hi joel thanks for the pointer. at the moment i'm not too fussed about the fulltext issue as there are not many rows. however your suggestion doesn't work, throwing the same mysql error as i was getting before??

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this:

`SELECT c.Category, t.tags, count(u.id) 

FROM Tags T

Left Join Categories c on c.id = t.category_id

Inner Join UsedTags u on u.value like '%' & t.tag & '%'`

the & may need to be replaced by your specific database (for instance in T-SQL it's the double pipe ||)

Comment: hi leslie, that sounds good too but it doesn't like the '%' & t.tag & '%' part (i'm using mysql 5.0.27)

Comment: so it seems that the mySQL concatenator can be the ||, so I would replace the % with ||.  
Or I also found this syntax that may work for you:
 like ConCAT( '%', t.tag, '%' )