# How to not likes many items in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

It's not gentlemanly to not like many items. But I need a query that `exclude` many items (`not in`) using a list of many items using `not like`.

```
| source |
|========|
| danny  |
| ram    |
| nach   |
| boom   |
| trach  |
| banana |

| key_exclude    |
|================|
| danny          |
| ram            |

| like_exclude   |
|================|
| bo             |
| tr             |
```

The expected results:

```
| result |
|========|
| banana |
| nach   |
```

I want to something like that:

```
select * from source where key not in (select key from key_exclude.key) 
  and key not like in(like_exclude.key)
```

But it is doesnt work

I can do:

```
select * from source where key not in (select key from key_exclude.key) 
  and key not like '%bo%' and key not like '%tr%'
```

The only problem is that the 'like_exclue' may contain hundreds of records.

Comment: I have read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127088/mysql-like-in but the answers them told him to add all the items to the `query`, but in this case it impossibile. I want the `like keys` will be in a table

Comment: Did you try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388323/adding-the-value-of-a-column-into-a-like-statement ?

Comment: I think your output should include 'nach'

Comment: @ZahiroMor you right

Comment: I see many answers (and some of them not tested). If someone can provide SQL Fiddle, will be much appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution query using subqueries:

```
select * 
from source AS s
where
    s.`key` not in( select k.`key` from key_exclude AS k ) AND
    NOT EXISTS( select 1 from like_exclude l WHERE s.`key` LIKE CONCAT('%', l.`key`, '%'));
```

Below is a full demo with data verified, also put on SQLFiddle by OP http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22fe8a/1/0

SQL:

```
-- Data
create table source(`key` char(20));
insert into source values
( 'danny' ),
( 'ram' ),
( 'nach' ),
( 'boom' ),
( 'trach' ),
( 'banana' );

create table key_exclude( `key` char(20));
insert into key_exclude values
( 'danny' ),
( 'ram' );

create table like_exclude( `key` char(20) );
insert into like_exclude values
( 'bo' ),
( 'tr' );

-- SQL Needed
select * 
from source AS s
where
    s.`key` not in( select k.`key` from key_exclude AS k ) AND
    NOT EXISTS( select 1 from like_exclude l WHERE s.`key` LIKE CONCAT('%', l.`key`, '%'));
```

Output:

```
mysql> select *
    -> from source AS s
    -> where
    -> s.`key` not in( select k.`key` from key_exclude AS k ) AND
    ->     NOT EXISTS( select 1 from like_exclude l WHERE s.`key` LIKE CONCAT('%', l.`key`, '%'));
+--------+
| key    |
+--------+
| nach   |
| banana |
+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Live Sample - SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22fe8a/1/0

Comment: Is that MySql? `ALL` in combination with `not like`? Never seen it.. and doesn't seem to work

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I forgot to add, in combination with `not like`.

Comment: Awesome man! It's really working.  Look here for a live example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22fe8a/1/0

Answer (score 2):

Let me first say that it is indeed very ungentlemanly not to like so many things. But sometimes you just have to...

Anyways..one way to do it is to use `RLIKE` in combination with `GROUP_CONCAT` instead of `LIKE`. That would result in something like this. This will probably go 'wrong' if there are special regexp characters inside the like_exclude table. What this would do performance wise is up to you, and with a lot of values in the table you might have to alter the `group_concat_max_len` value :

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8d79d/6)

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   source as s
WHERE 
   s.key NOT IN (SELECT ke.key FROM key_exclude as ke) 
   AND
   s.key NOT RLIKE (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(le.key SEPARATOR '|') FROM like_exclude as le);
```

Comment: Thanks. Why did you use `group_concat` and `rlike` here?

Comment: @Aminadav To create a regexpression with the | (or) seperator. Trust me, it works :D

Comment: Not working,group_concat not group when there are 100 rows

Comment: @Aminadav That's why i said you might have to alter the `group_concat_max_len`. To test you could try: `SET @@group_concat_max_len = 16384;`

Comment: Didn't success to change this variable on cloud SQL by Google. By thank's anyway.

Comment: @Aminadav Google cloud sql does have the option to change this value though. Check their documentation [https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-flags#config](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-flags#config)

Comment: You right, but it is not working. Right after setting it, it stays as 1024. I'm going to report this bug: http://snag.gy/U5Hfv.jpg

Comment: Unfortunately! According to the documentation you should change session variables in the `MySQL Flags section`. I am no user of cloud sql, so i do not know what they mean by that :). Good luck with it

Comment: You right. I found this flag, when editing an instance here: http://snag.gy/18uJd.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can use another not in to exclude the results that do answer the LIKE condition

```
select * from source
where key not in (select key from key_exclude.key) 
and key not in(select key from source
               where key LIKE (select concat('%',key,'%') from like_exclude.key)
```

But your query seems a little weird, you can't select from a column so I suspect you have to replace

```
 key_exclude.key -> key_exclude
```

And the other table too

```
like_exclude.key -> like_exclude
```

Comment: MySql don't have `minus` I believe

Comment: @Aminadav You're right my bad, I changed it to not in

Comment: Like. It's should work, but the another answer I think give much more performance that this

Comment: What ever suits you the best @Aminadav